# Get READ_CONTACT premission in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to read the contacts detail but when I run the code it give an error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
....
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2  .... requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arfan.myfirstapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You can check reset of my code how I try to read the contacts 
here is a link you can check it. [CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058584/implementing-loadercallbacks-in-activity-android)

Please tell me why I'm not able to get the permission. I'm new in android 
Thanks.

Comment: which device are you testing on?

Comment: Nexus 5 API 24 Android 7.0

Comment: Add that permission `runtime` as well.

Comment: you need to check if permission is granted by user or not. since API 23 app can't use some of the critical permission without user's permission. either you implement that part or just change your target SDK version to 22 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

replace your manifest with this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arfan.myfirstapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check the update question. I miss the permission while asking question in stackoverflow otherwise I already add this permission in my real project but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

This append because **from Android 6 the permission must be required at runtime**.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You must always required it in the manifest but if the device runs Android 6 or higher you must request to the user the permission, in the link you can find how