# Android getLoaderManager().initLoader saying that I can't use this

Tags: android

while I was developing an app for Android I encountered a problem with the LoaderManager. Whenever I try to use the following code:

`getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`

It tells me that I can't use this. here is a part of my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        insertNote("New Note");

        String[] from = {DBComHelper.NOTE_TEXT};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }
```

Here is the activity code:

```
package com.berendhulshof.privatenotes;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        insertNote("New Note");

        String[] from = {DBComHelper.NOTE_TEXT};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to, 0);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private void insertNote(String noteText) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBComHelper.NOTE_TEXT, noteText);
        Uri noteUri = 
        getContentResolver().insert(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Inserted note "  + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
    }

    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This question answer worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058584/implementing-loadercallbacks-in-activity-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a duplicate because some questions have this answer, but most of those questions also do not use the right imports. But I do. But the answer helped from this question: [Implementing LoaderCallbacks in Activity Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058584/implementing-loadercallbacks-in-activity-android)

I had to change getLoaderManager to getSupportloaderManager.

Answer (score 0):

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

This line wasn't supposed to work, as the `this` in the line is an activity, but the `initloader` method in this line accepts `LoaderCallbacks` interface, which has to be implemented separately.

Comment: I implemented it correctly, but the getLoaderManager should be getSupportloaderManager

Comment: I already noticed that you solved your problem - that's good for you. I just pointed out what was wrong in the first place - that is something you asked in your question explicitly.